# Can I buy one way ticket to Jamaica?

Tags: air-travel, passports, tickets, us-citizens, jamaica

Can I buy a one way ticket to Jamaica if I’m a us citizen. Born Jamaican with a expired Jamaican passport?

Comment: I think the questions you are actually after are “will I have any issue entering Jamaica with no return flight, US citizenship and an expired Jamaican passport?  Will the airline allow me to board?  Will the Jamaican immigration allow me entry?”  Anyone can buy a single leg ticket, thats the easiest part of this, as the airline or travel agency doesnt need to check your entry applicability on purchase.

Comment: Also check prices, in the past one way tickets often cost as much as or more than return tickets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.pica.gov.jm/immigration/travel-documents-required Jamaicans travelling on a Jamaican passport have an automatic right of entry into the island and do not require a visa to enter. Jamaican citizens are required to present the following documents to Immigration:

- A valid Jamaican passport, an emergency certificate or an expired Jamaican passport (providing acceptance from the airline)
- A completed and signed Immigration/Customs C5 form, either online or a physical form

So *yes, you can buy a one way ticket* but you should **check** the airline will allow you to board on that basis before doing so.

Also note the comment from @Willeke regarding the possible cost of one way tickets.

Answer assumes you have a valid US passport.